# Javascript: Date Issue while validating in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, validation

In Javascript function:

```
if (Tim2Val > Tim3Val && Tim2Val < Tim4Val)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

IF I have Variables like

```
Tim1Val=  8:00;
Tim2Val= 23:00;
Tim3Val= 01:00;
Tim4Val= 05:00
```

It is returning true. (It should return false. Can you please tell me how we can solve this?)

IF I have Variables like

```
Tim1Val=  8:00;
Tim2Val= 23:00;
Tim3Val= 02:00;
Tim4Val= 05:00;
```

It is returning false.

function fn_ConvTo24Format(MsTimeVal)
    {
     if(MsTimeVal=='')
     {
      return -1;
     }
     var A = MsTimeVal.split(/\D+/); 
     var locAMPos = MsTimeVal.indexOf('AM');
     var locPMPos = MsTimeVal.indexOf('PM');

```
 if(locAMPos ==-1 && locPMPos ==-1)
 {
  return MsTimeVal;
 }
 if(locAMPos!= -1 && A[0] + '.' + A[1]=='12.00' )
 {
  return 0;

 }
 if(locPMPos!= -1 && A[0] + '.' + A[1]=='12.00' )
 {
  return 12;

 }

 if(locAMPos!= -1 && A[0] + '.' + A[1]=='12.00' )
 {
  return 0;

 }

 if(locAMPos!= -1)
 {
  return A[0] + '.' + A[1];
 }
 if(locPMPos!= -1)
 {
  return (parseFloat(A[0]) + 12) + '.' + A[1];
 }

 return MsTimeVal;
}
```

Comment: Your IF statement does **NOT** consider/use Tim1Val at all. **And** as it stands now it is comparing strings, so the result is correct.

Comment: which way variables were initialized?

Comment: var MsTim1Val = fn_ConvTo24Format(MsTim1 );
     var MsTim2Val = fn_ConvTo24Format(MsTim2 );
     var MsTim3Val = fn_ConvTo24Format(MsTim3 );
     var MsTim4Val = fn_ConvTo24Format(MsTim4 );

Comment: and what makes fn_ConvTo24Format? I can't understand which data types is used.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not ever using Tim1Val is part of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose these values come in as string. If you compare the two, Javascript converts them to numbers, effectively changing their value.

"8:00" becomes 8 and minutes are ignored.

Maybe convert your hours and minutes in to just minutes:

```
function toMinutes (value) {
    var parts = value.split(":");
    return Number(value[0]) * 60 + Number(value[1]);
}

var Tim1Val = "8:00";
var Tim2Val = "23:00";
var Tim3Val = "2:00";
var Tim4Val = "5:00";



if (toMinutes(Tim1Val) > toMinutes(Tim3Val) && toMinutes(Tim2Val) < toMinutes(Tim4Val))
```

Oh and as Peter Wilkinson says, you never use Tim1Val.

Comment: var Tim1Val = "8:00";
var Tim2Val = "23:00";
var Tim3Val = "2:00";
var Tim4Val = "5:00"; Time3Val is next day morning 2AM and time4val is next day 5 am

Comment: If you know that Tim3Val and Tim4Val are the next day, just add 24 hrs to them. If you can't really know beforehand, consider using the Date object to gain more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns data of several types: string and numbers. 
Use one type make

```
...
if(locAMPos!= -1)
{
   return parseFloat(A[0] + '.' + A[1]);
}
....
```

I think it's not good way to make time comparation.
Will be better get Date class exemplar and work with it.